# Getting all "viewer" and "timestamp" using json

Tags: python

I'm trying to use json.loads to get all the "viewer" and "timestamp" and to get it just to output them. in a url but got stuck on doing it. This is the code:

```
elif used_prefix and cmd == "tracker" and self.getAccess(user) >= 1:
   try:
      if len(args) == 0:
        f = urlreq.urlopen("http://chtracker.info/index.py?output=html&x=page&y={}&results=0".format(user.name))
        data = json.loads(f.readall().decode("utf-8"))
        viewers = [(item['viewer'], item2['timestamp']) for item, item2 in data]
        room.message("The last 10 people who visited your profile: %s %s ago".format(item, stamp.getTimeStamp(item2)))
   except:
      room.message((str(sys.exc_info()[1])))
```

It goes like this in the url:

```
[{"viewer": "terraria11218", "timestamp": "1389575253.25377", "referer": "http://www.animefave.net/my-little-sister-cant-be-this-cute-season-2-episode-1/", "ip": "108.14.254.110", "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36", "page": "mechabot"}, {"viewer": "oruni", "timestamp": "1389574404.94542", "referer": "http://www.pinoyanime.tv/btooom-episode-3/", "ip": "75.187.235.72", "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.72 Safari/537.36", "page": "mechabot"}
```

Comment: Well I know how to get the first viewer but not the timestamp and I'm not sure how to get the other 9 viewers and timestamps.

Comment: Are you saying that the data that you show after 'It goes like this in the url:' is `data`, the value from the previous liken of code?

Comment: Yes thats the stuff. It goes on though on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you could do something like this:

```
>>> viewers = [(item['viewer'], item['timestamp']) for item in data]
[('terraria11218', '1389575253.25377'), ('oruni', '1389574404.94542')]
>>> viewers
[('terraria11218', '1389575253.25377'), ('oruni', '1389574404.94542')]
```

That assumes that every dictionary in the list has the keys 'viewer' and 'timestamp'.